# Мне нужно что-бы по нажатию кнопки c классом yesB к переменной ans прибавлялся 1 , как это можно сделать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```
$(document.getElementsByClassName('yesB')).click( () => {
  let ans = Number(ans) + 1;
});
```

Comment: Вы только что объявили переменную (в области видимости скобок), и присваиваете ей саму себя (ничто) + 1 ?

Comment: Вам только что намекнули. что объявлять переменную и придать ей какое-то начальное значение следовало бы не в самой функции, а до неё.

Comment: @Kromster а вас не смутило вот это `$(document.getElementsByClassName('yesB'))` ? %))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я недостаточно fluent в JS. Если вы разбираетесь - скажите прямо, что не так? )

Comment: @Kromster в jquery это пишется как `$(".yesB").click(...)`

Comment: @teran и в чем дело, написан некомпилируемый или недостижимый код? Или просто неоптимальный? )

Comment: @Kromster это какая то лютая помесь js с jquery

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо объявлить и инициализировать переменную ans за пределами функции.
Решение для JS:

```
let element = document.querySelector(".yesB"); 
let ans = 0; 

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
   ans = Number(ans) + 1;
});
```

Решение для JS с использованием DOMNode.matches:

```
let element = document.querySelector(".yesB");
let ans = 0;  

element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if (e.target.matches('.yesB')){
      ans = Number(ans) + 1;
   }
});
```

Решение для JQuery:

```
$('.yesB').attr("onClick", "ans++;");
```

Answer (score 0):

в JQuery думаю нет смысла использовать как селектор  document.getElementsByClassName('yesB'). Можно использовать такие же селекторы как и в CSS.

```
    let ans = 0;
    $('.yesB').on('click', function(){
        ans++;
    });
```

или

```
    let ans = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '.yesB', function(){
        ans++;
    });
```

https://api.jquery.com/on/